# Group pandas dataframe by hour and day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe covering a month of text with timestamp, something like this:

```
timestamp              text
2023-01-01 00:00:00    ABC
2023-01-01 00:00:01    DEF
2023-01-01 00:00:01    GHI
...
```

I would like to count the number of text for each hour and for each day of the week, so to have at the end 168 (24*7) numbers.

For example if the 2023-01-01, which is Sunday, between 10am and 11am there are 10 texts, the next Sunday (2023-01-08) always between 10am and 11am there are 15 texts, and so on. At the end the number of all texts for all the Sundays between 10am and 11am is: 10+15+...

I want to do this for each hour and for each day of the week.

If the original dataframe is `df`, I started to group by the hours:

```
hours_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="h")).size().reset_index(name="count_hours")
```

then I added the `day_of_week`:

```
hours_df["day_of_week"] = hours_df["timestamp"].dt.dayofweek
```

but if I group now by the `day_of_week` in this way:

```
day_df = hours_df.groupby("day_of_week").size().reset_index(name="count_days")
```

I am going to lose the info about the hours and the result is a dataframe with 7 entries, i.e. the days.

How I can combine the grouping of the hours with that of the days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly group by both dayofweek and hour:

```
df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.rename('dow'),
            df['timestamp'].dt.hour.rename('hour')
           ]).size()
```

Or using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
pd.concat([df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.rename('dow'),
           df['timestamp'].dt.hour.rename('hour')], axis=1
         ).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
dow  hour
6    0       3
dtype: int64
```

*NB. for a long enough input, you should have all combinations, if not you can always [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).*

---

Alternatively, for a rectangular output, use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.rename('dow'),
            df['timestamp'].dt.hour.rename('hour'))

# or for all values:
out = (pd.crosstab(df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.rename('dow'),
                   df['timestamp'].dt.hour.rename('hour'))
         .reindex(index=range(1, 7), columns=range(24), fill_value=0)
      )
```

Output:

```
hour  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
dow                                                                                                 
1      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6      3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```