# Calculate the mean by grouping pandas dataframe by hour and day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Based on one of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708538/group-pandas-dataframe-by-hour-and-day) I calculated the number of texts for each hour and for each day of the week:

```
time_df = df.groupby(
    [
        df["timestamp"].dt.dayofweek.rename("day_of_week"),
        df["timestamp"].dt.hour.rename("hour")
    ]
).size().reset_index(name="count")
```

This code return this output:

```
     day_of_week  hour   count
0            0.0   0.0   21195
1            0.0   1.0   13955
2            0.0   2.0   12767
3            0.0   3.0   17839
4            0.0   4.0   32762
..           ...   ...     ...
163          6.0  19.0  132838
164          6.0  20.0  129431
165          6.0  21.0  106678
166          6.0  22.0   69817
167          6.0  23.0   38262
[168 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now I would like to calculate the average number over the weekdays, i.e. the number in the column `count` has to be divided by the number of Mondays in the month if `day_of_week` is `0`, number of Tuesdays if it's `1` and so on.

If I change from `size()` to `mean()`, I obtain the error:

```
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]
```

and I this is not what I want.

I was trying to add a new column `day_of_week` to the original dataframe and count the number of blocks with the same value and then use it for the calculation, but I don't know how to do it...

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Sorry I was not clear about the dataframe.

The dataframe in the question is the only obtained from the original dataframe after the grouping, which means it contains 24 entries for each day of the week, one for each hour.

The original dataframe is something like this:

```
timestamp              text
2023-01-01 00:00:00    ABC
2023-01-01 00:00:01    DEF
2023-01-01 00:00:01    GHI
...
```

I added to this one a new column `day_of_week`:

```
timestamp              text  day_of_week
2023-01-01 00:00:00    ABC   6
2023-01-01 00:00:01    DEF   6
2023-01-01 00:00:01    GHI   6
...
```

and from this one I want to calculate the mean of the number of text for each hour and for each day of the week.

For example I have `21195` text at Monday at `0.0` and I have 4 Mondays in the month, the mean is: `21195 / 4 = 5298.75`, so the dataframe will be:

```
     day_of_week  hour   count  num_of_day_of_week  mean
0            0.0   0.0   21195  4                   5298.75
1            0.0   1.0   13955  4                   3488.75
2            0.0   2.0   12767  4                   3191.75
3            0.0   3.0   17839  4                   4459.75
4            0.0   4.0   32762  4                   8190.50
..           ...   ...     ...  ...                 ...
```

Sorry for the confusion, I hope now it's better.

Comment: So we need to know the real date of previous dataframe to extract the number of Sunday on January 2023 (4), Monday (5), etc? That's right? But the problem is on your second dataframe, we don't know if day_of_week and hour are for January, February, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy column to compute the mean on numeric column:
You can use:

```
df['mean'] = df['count'] / df['day_of_week'].map(df['day_of_week'].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     day_of_week  hour   count     mean
0            0.0   0.0   21195   4239.0
1            0.0   1.0   13955   2791.0
2            0.0   2.0   12767   2553.4
3            0.0   3.0   17839   3567.8
4            0.0   4.0   32762   6552.4
163          6.0  19.0  132838  26567.6
164          6.0  20.0  129431  25886.2
165          6.0  21.0  106678  21335.6
166          6.0  22.0   69817  13963.4
167          6.0  23.0   38262   7652.4
```

Another way is to use `groupby_transform`:

```
df['mean'] = df['count'] / df.groupby('day_of_week').transform('size')
```

Performance:

```
>>> %timeit df['day_of_week'].map(df['day_of_week'].value_counts())
292 µs ± 8.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.groupby('day_of_week').transform('size')
592 µs ± 6.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien thanks for the your answer, but I don't think it's what I want. I think in your method you count also the number of hours for each day, I just want the day. For example if in the dataset (and month) there are 4 Mondays the number of `count` has to be diveded by 4.
Running `df['day_of_week'].map(df['day_of_week'].value_counts())` the first vaIue I obtain is `2022208.0` which it's really huge.

Comment: Sorry I understand the confusion and I am going to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations:

1. Given code fails because it is trying to apply an aggregate function (mean) on a string column (text).
2. In the example 21195 is the number of "texts" on Monday at hour0. Remember this is across ALL months, weeks. So 21195 would be the sum of Monday hour0 texts in Jan + Monday hour0 texts in Feb ... so on. So dividing 21195 by 4 is arbitrary. Also, remember, some Months can have 5 Mondays.

From your question it sounds like you want to find weekly average of DoW,Hour wise texts for every month.

Add `Month`, `Week`, `DoW`, `HoD` columns to your original `df`:

```
df['Month'] = df['timestamp'].dt.month
df['Week'] = df['timestamp'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['DoW'] = df['timestamp'].dt.day_of_week
df['HoD'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour
```

Now find number of texts for every hour of every DoW  of every week of every month:

```
df_imm = df.groupby(['Month', 'Week', 'DoW', 'HoD'])['text'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

Now find the weekly average of DoW,Hour wise texts for every month:

```
result = df_imm.groupby(['Month', 'DoW', 'HoD'])['count'].mean().reset_index()
```

Note - Regarding point 2 if your data is restricted to a single month you can omit the Month column above since it won't make a difference but it is wise to future proof your code to handle future use cases as well.